# Ubuntu no longer detects external monitors

Tags: ubuntu, x11, multi-monitor

I have been working with two external monitors for most of a year using Ubuntu linux. Recently, I gave it the okay to update linux base. Upon rebooting, neither monitor came up. The displays settings window shows only the laptop display.

System:

- HP ZBook Fury 16 G9
- Ubuntu 22.04.3
- Kernel: 6.2.0-26-generic
- HDMI hub: VVB USB-C hub, currently bypassed
- Before that, a HODO hub

xrandr -q output shows only the laptop display:

```
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 220mm
   1680x1050     59.85*+
   1400x1050     59.86  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.78  
   1024x768      59.68  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.20  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.82  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77
```

What I've tried:

- Various reboot sequences: boot with monitors plugged in, boot with
  monitors not plugged in, unplugging individual monitors.
- Deleted monitors.xml (it recreated it with a single display)
- New hub
- Currently have a single monitor plugged into the built-in HDMI port
- Reinstalled the OS
- Multiple HDMI cables

While grasping at straws, I looked at kern.log. When restarting the display manager, I get this and I'm wondering if an updated apparmor could be blocking monitor detection:

```
Aug 17 20:02:30 Monster kernel: [ 3298.342817] audit: type=1400 audit(1692320550.336:102): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/19457/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=21365 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
Aug 17 20:02:30 Monster kernel: [ 3298.342835] audit: type=1400 audit(1692320550.336:103): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/19457/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=21365 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
Aug 17 20:02:30 Monster kernel: [ 3298.348602] rfkill: input handler disabled
Aug 17 20:02:30 Monster kernel: [ 3299.001174] audit: type=1107 audit(1692320550.992:104): pid=802 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.7" pid=21365 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=814 peer_label="unconfined"
Aug 17 20:02:30 Monster kernel: [ 3299.001174]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Aug 17 20:02:30 Monster kernel: [ 3299.001311] audit: type=1107 audit(1692320550.992:105): pid=802 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.7" pid=21365 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=814 peer_label="unconfined"
Aug 17 20:02:30 Monster kernel: [ 3299.001311]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Aug 17 20:02:31 Monster kernel: [ 3299.002502] audit: type=1107 audit(1692320550.996:106): pid=802 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.7" pid=21365 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=814 peer_label="unconfined"
Aug 17 20:02:31 Monster kernel: [ 3299.002502]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Aug 17 20:02:31 Monster kernel: [ 3299.002611] audit: type=1107 audit(1692320550.996:107): pid=802 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.7" pid=21365 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=814 peer_label="unconfined"
Aug 17 20:02:31 Monster kernel: [ 3299.002611]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Aug 17 20:02:31 Monster kernel: [ 3299.139272] audit: type=1400 audit(1692320551.132:108): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/etc/appstream.conf" pid=21365 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Aug 17 20:02:34 Monster kernel: [ 3302.954111] audit: type=1326 audit(1692320554.948:109): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=2 subj=snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software pid=21365 comm="pool-org.gnome." exe="/snap/snap-store/959/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=93 compat=0 ip=0x7f59aff94c4b code=0x50000
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, close as I can tell, the Ubuntu update did not include Nvidia drivers that work with it. I did a fresh install of Nvidia drivers and I'm back up and running.